# Obtaining information from user before answer is given?

Tags: discussion

The issue I am having trouble with is how to get information from a user **before** I can offer an answer.

The question(or statement) is: [Unable to connect Postgis from QGIS 1.8.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56593/unable-to-connect-postgis-from-qgis-1-8-0)

And it looks like the current answers are trying to help the OP troubleshoot or giving "*I think the problem is this*" kind of advice. It's easy to guess what the issue is but it's also possible - *given the right info from the OP* - to identify and solve the actual problem.

I think the OP just needs to take some Postgresql/PostGIS 101 (*not just read blogs, which is why I think they are here!*) classes or dive into the docs (*hard to use the docs without the jargon, ie - this user doesn't know what a service file is or how to use it*).

I think this user would get better help from the [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/community/)/[PostGIS](http://postgis.net/support) community Mailing Lists, IRC's, Forums or other direct communication with those communities.

## Options I've Considered:

- suggest to move it into Chat
- litter comments with inquiries for more info *(don't like this... b/c I already posted once*)
- modify original question with *blanks* for the OP to fill in (*ie, requesting specific info*)
- flag as "too localized" as I don't think this problem is wide spread and is related to this users specific setup (*did this*)

Comment: Good question. One immediate reaction: your third option (of inserting blanks) would not be approved (or quickly rolled back) as being too damaging to the original question. Whether you like it or not, the principal purpose of comments is to ask clarifying questions: this mechanism was originally created precisely to avoid damaging the questions while people sought to understand them. What we really need is a larger community of knowledgeable high-rep users who can vote intelligently to close (or leave open) such questions.

Comment: @whuber Thanks whuber. I'll keep on using comments to post _clarifying questions_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I mostly agree with Whuber. The current system works, comments and all. The OP got a suggested answer which has worked for him and he has marked the answer.  Comments asking for further information are instructive to the OP, they suggest new avenues of self help and lead to solutions to the problem posed.
I agree that we need a larger community of knowledgable high-rep users but primarily to help OPs to answer their questions, not vote to close them.